# Display Text Constantly

Tags: c#, text

I am very new to C# programming, and my main goal is to make simple text-based games. I am currently having a problem with my first one, which is the display of the player health and attack and monster health and attack values.

I want the values to be displayed at the top of the console and be updated every time the player's or monster's health is raised or lowered. The problem I am having is that I am currently limited to having this display as a different function from the rest, and I can only have it show when I run the function.

Like I said, I am very new to C# so my code is probably really clunky and amateurish.

```
   while (monsterHealth > 0 && playerHealthUpgraded > 0) 
        {
            DisplayStats ();

            Console.WriteLine ("You can either 'attack' or 'defend' yourself from the monster.");
            Console.WriteLine ("Attacking will decrease the monster's health by " + playerAttackUpgraded + " and defending yourself from the monster will cut the monster's attack value in half.");

            string input = Console.ReadLine ();

            if (input == "defend" || input == "attack" || input == "stimpak") 
            {

                switch (input) 
                {
                case "attack":
                    Console.Clear ();

                    DisplayStats ();

                    monsterHealth -= playerAttackUpgraded;
                    Console.WriteLine ("You raise your " + playerWeapon + " and fire several shots at the monster");
                    Console.WriteLine ("The monster's HP was lowered to " + monsterHealth + " by your attack.");

                    playerDamage += monsterAttack;
```

So obviously the "if" and "while" statements are closed at the end of the function.

Now, the thing that I want displayed constantly at the top of the console is "DisplayStats()", which  looks like this:

```
   public static void DisplayStats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Player Health: " + playerHealthUpgraded + "     Monster Health: " + monsterHealth);
        Console.WriteLine ("Player Attack: " + playerAttackUpgraded + "     Monster Attack: " + monsterAttack);
        Console.WriteLine (" ");
    }
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks,

-Liam

Comment: You can't use like this, since you are using console application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the lines flow backwards. However, you can use Console.Clear() to clear the console. So maybe you can try to redraw everything in your game loop, just as in other types of games.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a form based game personally since there's so much more you can do.

That being said, I think you're on the right track.

As Johnny was saying, you can redraw the text on every update.
If you need to, you can store all of the text in a string and refresh the console when you redraw the text.

Basically, add some methods to make writing/clearing the frame easier:

```
private static string frame;

public static void writeLine(string s) {
    frame += s + Environment.NewLine; //I believe "\n" works too
}
public static void write(string s) {
    frame += s;
}
public static void clearFrame() { frame = ""; }
public static void drawFrame() {
    Console.Clear();
    DisplayStats();
    Console.WriteLine(frame);
}
public static void DisplayStats() {
    Console.WriteLine("Player Health: " + playerHealthUpgraded + "\tMonster Health: " + monsterHealth);
    Console.WriteLine("Player Attack: " + playerAttackUpgraded + "\tMonster Attack: " + monsterAttack);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Then, your switch becomes:

```
switch (input) 
{
    case "attack":
        monsterHealth -= playerAttackUpgraded;
        writeLine("You raise your " + playerWeapon + " and fire several shots at the monster");
        writeLine("The monster's HP was lowered to " + monsterHealth + " by your attack.");

        playerDamage += monsterAttack;
        drawFrame();
```

This way, if you want, you can keep the text you already have, append it, or whatever you want to do.